# Generating Stereo Audio in PI programmatically

Tags: audio, python-3

I want a stereo output form the PI. The sound being played will not be a recorded sound rather it would be generated using a code (preferably python). For example, the program's input will be (x,y,z) coordinate of the sound source, Amplitude, The sound (maybe a monotone or a mix) and size of source.
The output shall be a stereo output such that i can identify the (x,y,z) coordinate  (like its done in a game- footstep sounds, firing sounds etc).

My question is how do do this using Python? Do i need some formal course on DSP (Digital Signal Processing) to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Python has several packages with bindings to OpenAL, which is widely used for 3D sound rendering. The most actively maintained package is [PyOpenAL](https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenAL/).

Answer (score -1):

There's very little DSP in what you want to do, merely mixing levels.  No idea if Python is up to it though, I always use C++.